# PHP. Как из массива строк перевести минуты в часы?

Tags: php, php7.4

Есть массив $str, которой содержит в себе следующие данные:

```
[0] => 1 час 25 минут

[1] =>  20 минут
```

Каким образом, из полученных данных, я могу перевести минуты в часы?

Comment: написать регулярное выражение, которое подходит под эти строки. вытащить данные, умножить часы на 60 и прибавить минуты

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
$data = ["1 час 25 минут","20 минут"];

$result = array_map(function($v){
                 if(preg_match("/((?<hour>\d+)\s*час)?.*?(?<min>\d+)\s*мин/iu", $v, $matches)){
                     
                     // часы
                     return intval($matches['hour'] ?? 0)  + $matches['min']/60;
                     // минуты
                     return intval($matches['hour'] ?? 0) * 60 + $matches['min'];
                 }
                 return 0;
              }, $data);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А если, например, пользователь введет 1,5 часа, то получается функция не отработает? Как изменить выражение, чтобы поддерживало два формата по типу: 
1. 1 час 30 минут
2. 1, 5 часа

Comment: @paci лучше не делать такие упоротые решения изначально. Например, либо чтобы часы минуты и секунды были в разных dropdown **без возможности писать час/мин/сек**, либо сразу использовать например календарь!